# выдаёт ошибку почему?

Tags: c#

Выдает такую ошибку

Assets\Fctivator.cs(16,14): error CS1061: 'Collider' does not contain a definition for 'ComareTag' and no accessible extension method 'ComareTag' accepting a first argument of type 'Collider' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Fctivator : MonoBehaviour

Comment: Это не ошибка это просто текст....

Comment: все я исправил привет

Comment: ок, только код стОит вставлять текстом, а не картинками. У сайта есть панель для форматирования кода, а также для вставки цитат

Comment: испаравить? или ответите?

Comment: Отвечу но исправить тоже не помешало бы. И в дальнейшем тоже это помнить

Comment: `Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(b)` - ты выводишь `b`, когда результат хранится в `a`.

Comment: @ИмронМухаммадов  для нового вопроса есть кнопка "задать вопрос". Не надо изменять текущий. Я всё откатил. Галочку верни и задавай новый

Comment: Я не могу почемуто заать меня забанило. Извини

Comment: Помогите с тем вопросом пж

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо писать не

```
other.CompareTag
```

а

```
other.gameObject.CompareTag
      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: спасибо в следующий раз буду писать вопросы правельно

Comment: @ИмронМухаммадов чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него

Comment: ПОМОГИИИ!!!!11111

Comment: @ИмронМухаммадов для нового вопроса есть кнопка "задать вопрос". Не надо изменять текущий. Я всё откатил. Галочку верни и задавай новый